# How can I change currency symbol in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm a beginner with WooCommerce and I have a question.
How can I change an existing currency symbol throughout the website.

I have tried this code but is not working :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
   switch( $currency ) {
      case 'د.م.': 
          $currency_symbol = 'MAD'; 
          break;
   }
   return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with code? You can do it in the settings page.

WooCommerce > Settings > General (tab) > Currency Options

[image]

**update:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {

    return ( $currency == 'MAD' ) ? $currency : $currency_symbol ;
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i did but i want to change the (د.م.) at (MAD)

Comment: you mean you want the word "MAD" ?

Comment: I want to change Currency Position  to Righ with space but does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'MAD': $currency_symbol = ' MAD'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add few lines of code in your theme's functions.php file

```
/**
 * Change a currency symbol
 */
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'د.م.': $currency_symbol = 'MAD'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```